# 1972 York Furnace wiring to a blower motor

Tags: wiring

This is a pic for an earlier question on the subject of wiring a blower motor with newer model (motor)...the new model has extra wires the old motor did not have.  I don't know what to do with two extra black wires.  And not to sure what to do with the brown and the brown/white wires to the capacitor.  Please help ...heat is killing me.[image: This is the new blower motor]

Comment: Is this a photo of the new motor? What's the make and model of the furnace?  Can you include a similar photo of the old motor?

Answer (score 1):

The wiring diagram is printed on the side of the motor.

[image]

#### Brown, Brown/White

The Brown and Brown with White wires go to the run capacitor. If the old motor did not have a capacitor, you'll need to get a [10 microfarad 370 VAC capacitor](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Packard-370-Volt-10-MFD-Motor-Run-Oval-Capacitor-TOC10/204415820). Mount the capacitor, and connect these wires to it.

#### Yellow

The yellow wire is one of the line wires. It will either go to L2 or neutral, depending on the motor and the system it is installed in.

#### Black, Blue, Red

These wires are the speed taps. You'll connect **one** of them to power at a time, to make the motor spin at the desired speed. Black is high, Blue is medium, and Red is low speed. In some furnaces/air handlers, you'll simply park each tap at the corresponding terminal on the fan control module.

#### Rotation Direction

This motor also allows you to select the rotation direction, by simply connecting four wires in the appropriate configuration.

Comment: i am not an electrical person , the   diagram really dose nothing for me . . need to see a picture of the wires connected to the capacitor from the blower motor

Comment: @JamesJackson if you include the model number of the furnace,  or a clear photo of the schematic printed inside the unit, I can draw you a picture.

Comment: i got all my wiring done correctly , had to get a transformer , it is connected correctly . . my new problem is this before i had all the wiring done i had to still figure out where the yellow wire goes , so what i done was accidentally touch the yellow wire to the side of the housing ,,was not good out come so could this have blown out my capacitor